# db.createIndex is not a function

Tags: angular, pouchdb, ionic3

I am working with Ionic 3, Angular 4, Pouchdb, Pouchdb-find
Pouchdb works fine.
I have installed both pouchdb and pouchdb-find via npm

steps to reproduce

npm

```
ionic start testapp
npm install pouchdb
npm install pouchdb-find
ionic serve -l
```

here is a brief of my component using a blank ionic 3 template

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
declare var require: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {


    PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));

    var db = new PouchDB('pillsalarm3');

    db.createIndex({
      index: {fields: ['type']}
    });
  }           
}
```

when I run I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: db.createIndex is not a function TypeError: db.createIndex is not a function at new HomePage (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:57:12) at createClass (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:11251:26) at createDirectiveInstance

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, it's because it's bundled as an ES6 module with a default export.

With `PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find').default);`it works. 
Alternatively :

```
import findPlugin from "pouchdb-find";
PouchDB.plugin(findPlugin);
```

Also works :)

Comment: Hi, great. thanks very much. it solved it but created another error. this is what i get now.

Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:145934:101 at t.invoke